# Convert DD (decimal degrees) to DMS (degrees minutes seconds) in Python?

Tags: python, angle, degrees, format-conversion, unit-conversion

How do you convert Decimal Degrees to Degrees Minutes Seconds In Python? Is there a Formula already written?

Comment: @David: it's a matter of multiplying decimal part by 60. What do you need beyond that?

Answer (score 28):

This is exactly what `divmod` was invented for:

```
def decdeg2dms(dd):
    mult = -1 if dd < 0 else 1
    mnt,sec = divmod(abs(dd)*3600, 60)
    deg,mnt = divmod(mnt, 60)
    return mult*deg, mult*mnt, mult*sec

dd = 45 + 30/60 + 1/3600
print(decdeg2dms(dd))

# negative value returns all negative elements
print(decdeg2dms(-122.442))
```

Prints:

```
(45.0, 30.0, 1.0)
(-122.0, -26.0, -31.199999999953434)
```

Comment: It doesn't work with negative. -122.442 returns (-123,33,28.8). Should be (-122,26,31.12)

Comment: @baens - do you mean `(-122, -26, -31.12)`?  I think `-123 + 33/60 + 28.8/3600` does in fact equal `-122.442`

Comment: A multiplication by 3600, followed by 2 divisions by 60, doesn't look as efficient as possible.

Comment: As said by @erik-l it gives wrong results for negative angles and must be corrected

Comment: Only took 10 years, but here is a solution where all values are positive or negative, not mixed.

Answer (score 17):

Here is my updated version based upon Paul McGuire's. This one should handle negatives correctly.

```
def decdeg2dms(dd):
   is_positive = dd >= 0
   dd = abs(dd)
   minutes,seconds = divmod(dd*3600,60)
   degrees,minutes = divmod(minutes,60)
   degrees = degrees if is_positive else -degrees
   return (degrees,minutes,seconds)
```

Comment: `minutes` and `seconds` also need to be negated if `is_positive` is False.

Answer (score 14):

If you want to handle negatives properly, the first non-zero measure is set negative. It is counter to common practice to specify all of degrees, minutes and seconds as negative ([Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geographic_coordinate_conversion) shows 40° 26.7717, -79° 56.93172 as a valid example of degrees-minutes notation, in which degrees are negative and minutes have no sign), and setting degrees as negative does not have any effect if the degrees portion is 0. Here is a function that adequately handles this, based on Paul McGuire's and baens' functions:

```
def decdeg2dms(dd):
    negative = dd < 0
    dd = abs(dd)
    minutes,seconds = divmod(dd*3600,60)
    degrees,minutes = divmod(minutes,60)
    if negative:
        if degrees > 0:
            degrees = -degrees
        elif minutes > 0:
            minutes = -minutes
        else:
            seconds = -seconds
    return (degrees,minutes,seconds)
```

Answer (score 8):

Just a couple of `* 60` multiplications and a couple of `int` truncations, i.e.:

```
>>> decdegrees = 31.125
>>> degrees = int(decdegrees)
>>> temp = 60 * (decdegrees - degrees)
>>> minutes = int(temp)
>>> seconds = 60 * (temp - minutes)
>>> print degrees, minutes, seconds
31 7 30.0
>>>
```

Answer (score 5):

This is my Python code:

```
def DecimaltoDMS(Decimal):
    d = int(Decimal)
    m = int((Decimal - d) * 60)
    s = (Decimal - d - m/60) * 3600.00
    z= round(s, 2)
    if d >= 0:
        print ("N ", abs(d), "º ", abs(m), "' ", abs(z), '" ')
    else:
        print ("S ", abs(d), "º ", abs(m), "' ", abs(z), '" ')
```

Comment: Using `Decimal` as a variable name may conflict with `decimal.Decimal` and is not a good idea.

Answer (score 5):

Improving @chqrlie answer:

```
    def deg_to_dms(deg, type='lat'):
        decimals, number = math.modf(deg)
        d = int(number)
        m = int(decimals * 60)
        s = (deg - d - m / 60) * 3600.00
        compass = {
            'lat': ('N','S'),
            'lon': ('E','W')
        }
        compass_str = compass[type][0 if d >= 0 else 1]
        return '{}º{}\'{:.2f}"{}'.format(abs(d), abs(m), abs(s), compass_str)
```

Answer (score 4):

Here's my slightly different approach that works the same as on my HP Prime for positive and negative decimal degrees...

```
def dms(deg):
    f,d = math.modf(deg)
    s,m = math.modf(abs(f) * 60)
    return (d,m,s * 60)
```

Answer (score 3):

The sign has better be returned separately, so that it can be used to choose from `('N', 'S')` or `('E', 'W')`, for example.

```
import math

def dd_to_dms(degs):
    neg = degs < 0
    degs = (-1) ** neg * degs
    degs, d_int = math.modf(degs)
    mins, m_int = math.modf(60 * degs)
    secs        =           60 * mins
    return neg, d_int, m_int, secs
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a numpy version of PaulMcG's answer with the addition that it will round to tenths of a second (you can change second argument to round function) and it returns the sign (-1 or 1) as a separate value (this made it easier for me to handle as latitude/longitude values). Main difference here is that you can pass in an array of decimal_degrees or a single double value (note if you pass a list you get a list-of-lists back).  Before using please make sure you are happy with the rounding behavior or you can remove it.

```
def to_dms(decimal_degrees):
    # convert degrees into dms and a sign indicator
    degrees = np.array(decimal_degrees)
    sign = np.where(degrees < 0, -1, 1)
    r, s = np.divmod(np.round(np.abs(degrees) * 3600, 1), 60)
    d, m = np.divmod(r, 60)
    # np.transpose([d, m, s]*sign)  # if you wanted signed results
    return np.transpose([d, m, s, sign])

# print("array test:", to_dms([101.816652, -101.816653]))
# array test: [[101. 48. 59.9000000000232831 1.] [101. 49. 0. -1.]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `fmod` and rounding to get the degrees and fraction separated. Multiply the fraction by 60 and repeat to get minutes and a remainder. Then multiply that last part by 60 again to get the number of seconds.

Comment: You probably meant `math.modf`.

Answer (score 0):

Now we can use LatLon library...

https://pypi.org/project/LatLon/

```
>> palmyra = LatLon(Latitude(5.8833), Longitude(-162.0833)) # Location of Palmyra Atoll in decimal degrees
>> palmyra = LatLon(5.8833, -162.0833) # Same thing but simpler! 
>> palmyra = LatLon(Latitude(degree = 5, minute = 52, second = 59.88),
                     Longitude(degree = -162, minute = -4.998) # or more complicated!
>> print palmyra.to_string('d% %m% %S% %H') # Print coordinates to degree minute second
('5 52 59.88 N', '162 4 59.88 W')`
```

Comment: The version you linked is only tested to Python 2.7. There is a newer version, but even that one is only tested to Python 3.6 https://pypi.org/project/latlon3

Comment: Hi, what I am using now is LatLon23 in my Python 3.7.4
https://pypi.org/project/LatLon23/#description

Comment: That's great. It seems to be working with 3.9 as well. It's more straightforward than Geographiclib,  which is what I ended up with.

Comment: Just a note for users following the documentation that says that you import the module using the syntax `import latlon`   You need to use the following `from latlon import LatLon` to make these examples work.  Note the case

Answer (score 0):

You can use the function [`clean_lat_long()`](https://docs.dataprep.ai/user_guide/clean/clean_lat_long.html) from the library [DataPrep](https://dataprep.ai/) if your data is in a DataFrame. Install DataPrep with `pip install dataprep`.

```py
from dataprep.clean import clean_lat_long
df = pd.DataFrame({"coord": [(45.5003, -122.4420), (5.8833, -162.0833)]})

df2 = clean_lat_long(df, "coord", output_format="dms")
# print(df2)
                 coord                        coord_clean
0  (45.5003, -122.442)  45° 30′ 1.08″ N, 122° 26′ 31.2″ W
1  (5.8833, -162.0833)  5° 52′ 59.88″ N, 162° 4′ 59.88″ W
```

Or if latitude and longitude are in separate columns:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({"latitude": [45.5003, 5.8833], "longitude": [-122.4420, -162.0833]})

df2 = clean_lat_long(df, lat_col="latitude", long_col="longitude", output_format="dms")
# print(df2)
   latitude  longitude                 latitude_longitude
0   45.5003  -122.4420  45° 30′ 1.08″ N, 122° 26′ 31.2″ W
1    5.8833  -162.0833  5° 52′ 59.88″ N, 162° 4′ 59.88″ W
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
# Program to convert degree to Degree, Minutes and Seconds
# Using try and except for int data validations
try:

    # Requesting input degree from user
    print ("degree to Degree Minutes seconds converter ". upper ())
    degree = float(input ("\nEnter Degree: "))
    
    # Casting input from float to int 
    degree_d = int(degree)
    
    # Working on minutes
    minute =60 * (degree - degree_d)
    minutes = int(minute)
    
    # Working on seconds
    second = 60 * (minute - minutes)
    # Rounding seconds to whole number 
    seconds= round(second)
    
    # print 
    print (f"\nThe Answer In Degree-Minutes-Seconds are: \n{degree_d}°{minutes}'{seconds}\"  ✓\n ") 


#Except

except ValueError:
    print ("Wrong Input ")
```

Answer (score 0):

My approach:

```
import sys
import math

dd = float(sys.argv[1])
f,d = math.modf(dd)
f,m = math.modf(60*f)
s = round(60*f, 6)

print(int(d), int(m), s)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Testing with math.degrees(1.777036) and rounding set to 1 decimal place on seconds you get (101 48 60.0) -- any simplistic conversion that rounds will have this kind of issue.

Answer (score -1):

```py
def dms_to_deg(dms):
    import math
    import numpy as np
    a=math.fabs(dms)
    d=a//10000
    m=(a-d*10000)//100
    s=(a-d*10000-m*100)
    deg=(d+m/60+s/3600)*np.sign(dms)
    return deg

#---Usage
r1=dms_to_deg(243055.25)
r2=dms_to_deg(-243055.25)
print(r1,r2)
```

Comment: A Python function to Convert degree minutes seconds to degree decimal for both positive and negative numbers. Check Example in Usage.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).