# How can you split a decimal number at the decimal to get minutes and seconds? Python

Tags: python, split

Say I have a variable called

```
time = 6.50
```

how can I split the number so that I can output to the user:

```
print("Your total time was %i minutes and %i seconds. " %(minute, second))
```

I thought about converting them to string but I need to be able to multiply the .50 part by 60 so I can get the total seconds.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2579535/how-to-convert-dd-to-dms-in-python

Answer (score 3):

You can also use `divmod` , as -

```
minutes, seconds = divmod(int(time * 60), 60)
```

If you want the seconds to also have millisecond (floating point precision) , you can remove the conversion to `int` and do - `divmod(time * 60, 60)` .

Demo -

```
>>> time = 6.50
>>> divmod(time * 60, 60)
(6.0, 30.0)
>>> time = 6.55
>>> divmod(time * 60, 60)
(6.0, 33.0)
>>> time = 6.53
>>> divmod(time * 60, 60)
(6.0, 31.80000000000001)
>>> time = 6.55
>>> divmod(int(time * 60), 60)
(6, 33)
```

But please note, floating point arithematic is not precise, so you may get approximate values instead of exact accurate results.

Answer (score 2):

```
time = 6.50
minute, second = int(time), (time%1)*60
print("Your total time was %i minutes and %i seconds. " %(minute, second))
```